# Monitor the lifecycle of each turtle (NetLogo)

Tags: netlogo

I have a question on how to "monitor" through time some turtles. You can think of this problem like plotting the lifecycle of each turtle.
Let's say initially I have 5 turtles. At each tick, a new turtle is created.
They do some actions (e.g., each of them interacts with a dummy turtle) before their death.
I can identify the turtle created at each tick using `who`.
I have tried as follows:

```
  create-temporary-plot-pen (word "Turtle " (who))
  set-plot-pen-color color  
  plotxy ticks count XX ;(# of interactions between who and the dummy variable through time)
```

but nothing is displayed on the chart. Only the list of turtles that at each tick are created is correctly displayed.

The desired plot should show how many times each turtle interacts with the dummy variable before it dies.
I hope it makes sense to you. If it does not, I will be happy to answer all the question you can have.